# Назначение пула соединений в Java

Tags: java

Пул соединений в Java является выгодной альтернативной реализации соединения с БД с помощью паттерна Singleton?

Comment: Пул коннектов, это не обязательно 1 коннект, поэтому это не совсем похожие вещи. Пул служит больше для быстроты обращения к бд, ибо коннект висит открытым и просто выдаётся пользователю, и вместо закрытия просто возвращается в пул. А синглтон это всё же шаблон.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы спрашиваете есть ли у пула соединений преимущества, то ответ - да, есть. Что имеется в виду под "реализацией соединения с помощью Singleton" я, честно говоря, не понимаю. Пул соединений - это когда сразу открывается несколько соединений к БД и дальнейшие запросы к БД будут проходить через уже открытые соединения вместо ожидания открытия нового соединения.

Comment: _"реализацией соединения с помощью Singleton"_ - это когда открыто одно соединение (имеется только один экземпляр класса:)), и все по очереди получают к нему доступ, само собой это очень медленно когда желающих много, но иногда такое соединение имеет смысл.

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков не вижу преимуществ в одном соединении, разве что приложение совсем небольшое и ожидаемое количество запросов к бд соответствующее(требуется профилирование чтобы понять когда этот момент становится "bottleneck") и если требуется экономия ресурсов. Для профилирования могу посоветовать jprofiler - инструмент крутой и платный, но есть пробная версия